# Background image moves but element doesn't move with it

Tags: css, position

Noob here...
I'm trying to display an element on a fixed image but when I resize my screen (to see if it's responsive) the background image shrinks. Now, it works when I simply have this code in:

**position: relative; 

background: url("https://www.pngitem.com/pimgs/m/189-1891044_hand-holding-phone-hand-holding-iphone-png-transparent.png"); 

object-fit: fill;

background-repeat:no-repeat;**

but as soon as I add the background size and position:

**background-position: 57% 5%; 

background-size:40%;**

the image doesn't stay in place. Any idea why or how to fix this?

Comment: Please put the HTML code into your question along with the CSS and make it a working snippet. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with doing this. I didn't fully understand 'display an element on a fixed image'. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

`background-position: 57% 5%;` will move your image 57% horizontally and 5% vertically. However, if you want a background-image that will not scroll with the page you may use `background-attachment: fixed;`.

Comment: I've tried that but it didn't work :/

Comment: oooh so you mean remove the position and simply keep the attachment?! I'll try that and get back to you!

Comment: It didn't work either :/ Here is my codepen link: https://codepen.io/sararita28/pen/gOxvNEo
Basically, whenever you try to make the screen size smaller, the background image gets smaller and doesn't stay in the same position while the element (calculator) stays in place